# SQL - Previous Seven Days Sale (Per Customer, Per Date)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Based on a table that contains a CustomerID, Date and Daily Sales field, I need to calculate the previous 7 days of sales per CustomerID, Date combination. Sample data as follows:

```
CustomerID  Date    Daily Sales
    1   10/18/16    $100
    1   10/17/16    $50
    1   9/1/16  $20
    1   8/5/16  $20
    1   7/1/16  $20
    1   6/15/16 $20
    1   1/1/16  $20
    2   10/18/16    $50
    2   10/17/16    $50
    2   10/16/16    $50
    2   10/15/16    $50
    2   10/14/16    $50
```

Desired output is as follows:

```
CustomerID  Date    Daily Sales Last 7 Days Sales
1   10/18/16    $100    $150
1   10/17/16    $50 $50
1   9/1/16  $20 $20
1   8/5/16  $20 $20
1   7/1/16  $20 $20
1   6/15/16 $20 $20
1   1/1/16  $20 $20
2   10/18/16    $50 $250
2   10/17/16    $50 $200
2   10/16/16    $50 $150
2   10/15/16    $50 $100
2   10/14/16    $50 $50
```

Here is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT
t1.[CustomerID]
,CAST(t1.[Date] AS DATE) AS Date
,SUM(t1.[DailySales]) AS [DailySales]
,SUM(t2.[DailySales]) AS [Last7DaysSales]
FROM TABLE_NAME t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_NAME t2 ON t1.[CustomerID] = t2.[CustomerID]
AND CAST(t2.[Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, t1.[Date]) and t1.[Date]

GROUP BY t1.[CustomerID], CAST(t1.[Date] AS DATE)
ORDER BY t1.[CustomerID], CAST(t1.[Date] AS DATE) DESC;
```

Values are returned as expected for Last7DaysSales, however are incorrect for sales for just that day. I'm sure I'm doing something silly with my join that is causing the issue...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should share with us what you have done so far and what problems you are facing. Please view this page to see how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Andrew, I'm probably being a idiot here with my join (new to SQL) - with this query, I'm able to correctly get Last7DaysSales (per customer, per each date), however it is returning the incorrect sales for just that individual date! Again, I'm sure I'm being an idiot.. I've edited my post to provide the query.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(Column) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date < (GETDATE()-7) AND CustomerId=1`  - gives you daily sales sum for the customer id = 1.

Comment: Hi Vlad - I need to return the previous 7 days of sales, per customer, for each day within the dataset (rather than just the previous -7 days from GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the base query to get everything EXCEPT the Last7DaysSales value, and then calculate that with a subquery:

```
SELECT
t1.[CustomerID]
,CAST(t1.[Date] AS DATE) AS Date
,SUM(t1.[DailySales]) AS [DailySales]
,(select sum(t2.[DailySales]) 
  from TABLE_NAME t2 
  where t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
  and cast(t2.[Date] as date) between dateadd(day, -7, cast(t1.[Date] as date)) and cast(t1.[Date] as date)
 ) as [Last7DaysSales]
FROM TABLE_NAME t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_NAME t2 ON t1.[CustomerID] = t2.[CustomerID]
AND CAST(t2.[Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, t1.[Date]) and t1.[Date]
GROUP BY t1.[CustomerID], CAST(t1.[Date] AS DATE)
ORDER BY t1.[CustomerID], CAST(t1.[Date] AS DATE) DESC;
```

Note that Window Functions are a more efficient way to do this, but this method is probably a bit more intuitive.